# Does an Alcatel 7750 emulator/simulator exist?

Tags: networking, router, emulation

My company recently deployed several Alcatel-based networks (7750SR) for ethernet and IP transport, and me and my team will have to support a part of it.

We're quite used to troubleshoot on Cisco and Juniper routers, but Alcatel-Lucent TiMOS is new to us and really different.

While we can have access to lab devices, I'd like to know if there is any emulator or simulator of ALU routers on which we can practice and test some configs.

I tried to search both on Internet and corporate intranet, but I don't even know what to look for...

Comment: We do have access to original software, so I guess there won't be any licence issue.

Comment: Have you consider making contact with your organization's Alcatel account team for assistance?

Comment: @user48838: my company is so large (180k+) I don't even know who's in touch with vendors... :(

Comment: Follow the money... Which group/department ultimately makes the purchases with/through Alcatel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since some time now, [the tool is now available](http://www.alcatelunleashed.com/viewtopic.php?f=364&t=23652) to customers.

It's included with the usual 7750 SR-OS releases.

It's a qcow2 image, and they provide the instructions to run it within a kvm hypervisor.

I don't have any informations about pricing, but without a license file it will still run for 1 hour before reloading.

The "vSim" SR-OS is limited in terms of pps (250pps IIRC), and there is another release, "vRR" that's intended for production use as a route-reflector.

Answer (score 1):

It exists within Alcatel-Lucent. They use it for classroom instruction. I used it taking the  Alcatel-Lucent Scalable IP Networks 4A0100 class.
They will not let you have it. Many have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Go to this web site http://www3.alcatel-lucent.com/wps/portal/src/mysrlab. You can purchase time from ALU so that you can practice your configurations and prepare for the exams.